# Cross-Domain Ajax throwing No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error but network tab is showing response data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I have a script that takes the user's UPS Tracking number and gets the tracking information back from the UPS JSON Tracking API through a cross-domain AJAX request (using jQuery.ajax). Everything worked perfectly up until about two weeks ago.

Then, out of the blue, every request fails due to the infamous "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error.

The thing is, the request *is* still properly getting through. If I check the network tab in the Chrome Dev Tools, I can see a status code of 200 in the headers. Clicking on the Preview or Response tabs, I can see the correct JSON response that should be returned.

First of all, I'm stumped as to how I am getting an appropriate response if my origin is not allowed access. Second, is there any way to let this error happen and still get access to the response? I've tried getting the xhr object from the "error" and "complete" callbacks (using jQuery.ajax) but I can only access the error object.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: json,
    success: function(data){
            cb(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        console.log(xhr, status, error);
        // logs: {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status){
        console.log(xhr, status);
        // also logs: {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}
    }
});
```

Comment: Same Origin Policy, you can not access other domains unless they let you.

Comment: *"Second, is there any way to let this error happen and still get access to the response?"* **No.** you must fix the CORS issue that was apparently introduced 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Maybe UPS changed something recently. There seems to be some developer documentation you can download from https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit that might have up-to-date info.

Comment: I understand the limitations regarding Same Origin Policy, but I'm most confused as to how I'm getting a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error but still showing a valid response in Dev Tools. Usually I would just get "No response data available" or something along those lines. If the server is rejecting access, why am I still getting any response, let alone a vaild one?

Answer (score 2):

in fact it is a problem of cross domain you have multiple solutions to remedy :

read about cross domain : [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Added to the header of your request

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Or allowed the cross domain in the browser you use :

```
Chromium-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

On safari:

```
Development > Disable Multi-Origin restriction
```